# SQL - add a column with count over another colums

Tags: sql

Regarding the sample below, i'd like to add a column 'fft_sales' counting the distinct ticket_numbers associted to fft_ref.

In the desired table :
3 is the count of distinct ticket numbers for fft_ref = 1
2 is the count of distinct ticket numbers for fft_ref = 2

In big query SQL

Thanks

[image: existing]

[image: desired]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following select with an extra subquery:

```
Select 
T1.Ticket_num, 
T1.fft_ref, 
T1.assoc_ref, 
(Select Count(*) From TableName Where fft_ref = T1.fft_ref Group by ticket_num) as fft_sales
from TableName T1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this.  If your database supports it:

```
select t.*,
       count(distinct ticket_num) over (partition by fft_ref) as fft_sales
from t;
```

Many databases do not support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  But there is a simple work-around using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
       (dense_rank() over (partition by fft_ref order by fft_ref asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by fft_ref order by fft_ref desc) -
        1
       ) as fft_sales
from t;
```

Comment: The first solution works fine. Thanks Gordon !